# Google Sheets Conditional Formatting based on two cells having matching numbers

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I would like to highlight every row where the numbers in Columns F and G match. This works perfectly, with text (a-z), as answered in this thread:

[Google Sheets Conditional Formatting based on two cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31293966/google-sheets-conditional-formatting-based-on-two-cells/36686946#36686946?newreg=7602550dd5d04c9ab3a4d4af80f73c7f)

But, I am not sure how to make it work when it's a number. Any advice appreciated!

Comment: What did you try already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply custom-formula conditional formatting of `=$F1=$G1` to the whole range you wish to affect.

Change the 1's to the row number that is the first row in your selected range. E.g. If applying to A5:H, the formula would be `=$F5=$G5`.

Comment: Thank you so much!  That works.  Is there a way to have the formula ignore values of 0?  Example: Row 3 of this sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EnVSMEbvDnA9IrN0Wvqje2pgor0uHcfCJozlxYleXJc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: =AND($F1=$G1,$F1<>0)