# Color Rows in part of a For Loop that assigns categories to form submissions

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a for loop that is set on a trigger on form submit. Each time something is submitted, it checks to see if a line has been categorized. If not, it adds a category. I would like to include color assignment as an additional step to the categorization. If categorized A, then blue, if B then yellow.

I've tried the code below based on other StackOverflow posts. No luck.

```
function eventCategorization() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var activeSheet = sheet.setActiveSheet(sheet.getSheetByName('Form Responses 1')); //Update Sheet Name here
  Logger.log("sheet: " + activeSheet.getSheetName());

  var startRow = 3;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = activeSheet.getLastRow() - 1;   // Number of rows to process
  var totalColumns = activeSheet.getMaxColumns();

  // Fetch the range of all cells with responses
  var dataRange = activeSheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, totalColumns)
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];  
    var broadEventType = row[11];
    Logger.log("broadEventType: "+broadEventType);

    var groupedEvent = row[1];
    Logger.log("groupedEvent: "+groupedEvent)

    if (groupedEvent ==""){
      if (broadEventType =="Gala"){
        activeSheet.getRange(i+3,2).setFormulaR1C1('="Expensive"');
        row.getRow().setBackgroundColor("#99CC99");
        activeSheet.getRange(i+3,2).getRow().setBackgroundColor("#99CC99");
      }
    }
    else if(broadEventType =="Picnic"|| 
            broadEventType=="Beach Trip"||
            broadEventType=="Drinks"){
      activeSheet.getRange(i+3,2).setFormulaR1C1('="Cheap"');
      activeSheet.getRange(i+3,2).getRow().setBackgroundColor("#4286f4");
    }
  }  
}
```

Error message:

> TypeError: Cannot find function getRow in object ,,Y,Y,Jill DesRosier,424584515,,,,,,Internal

Comment: " row.getRow().setBackgroundColor("#99CC99");" is trying to set a color on an array, getRow can only be used in the page itself. comment out the row.getRow and your code should work. Although, you also would be cleaner to not use getRow at all, getRange(i+3,1,1,10).setBackgroundColor("blue");

Answer (score 1):

```
function eventCategorization() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var activeSheet = sheet.setActiveSheet(sheet.getSheetByName('Form Responses 1')); //Update Sheet Name here
  Logger.log("sheet: " + activeSheet.getSheetName());

  var startRow = 3;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = activeSheet.getLastRow() - 1;   // Number of rows to process
  var totalColumns = activeSheet.getMaxColumns();

  // Fetch the range of all cells with responses
  var dataRange = activeSheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, totalColumns)
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];  
    var broadEventType = row[11];
    Logger.log("broadEventType: "+broadEventType);

    var groupedEvent = row[1];
    Logger.log("groupedEvent: "+groupedEvent)

    if (groupedEvent ==""){
      if (broadEventType =="Gala"){
        activeSheet.getRange(i+3,2).setFormulaR1C1('="Expensive"');
        var activeRow = activeSheet.getRange(i+3,1,1,totalColumns).setBackgroundColor("#CC6666");
      }
    }
    else if(broadEventType =="Picnic"|| 
            broadEventType=="Beach Trip"||
            broadEventType=="Drinks"){
      activeSheet.getRange(i+3,2).setFormulaR1C1('="Cheap"');
var activeRow = activeSheet.getRange(i+3,1,1,totalColumns).setBackgroundColor("#4286f4");
    }
  }  
}
```

Comment: Provide brief explanations. Code only answers doesn't help future viewers much.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that coloring rows using conditional formatting is much easier than trying to set the color explicitly.

You can set the color for a whole row based on the contents of one or more cells in the row.

[Google Sheets Conditional Formatting based on two cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31293966/google-sheets-conditional-formatting-based-on-two-cells)